# How to add css manually to flutter webview application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want to convert a website to app via flutter. But in in converted app, I don't need the header and the footer of the website. I want to remove them via manual CSS.
so, how can I do this?